# why python gives me extra floating-point number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, floating-point

I'm doing a simple addition "11111.66+1111.38+60000" using python. Why python gives me "72223.04000000001" rather than "72223.04"?

I've tried python2.7.12/Python3.5.2 in Linux and Python3.7.2 in Windows.

11111.66+1111.38+60000

Answer (score 0):

This is a run-of-the-mill floating point coding issue, it's not an error. It just reflects the way numbers are represented in the belly of the machine.

Try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
float(Decimal(11111.66)+Decimal(1111.38)+Decimal(60000))
```

Where the decimal library irons out these little squiggles.

More here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html